# Ubuntu 22.04 no sound Issue

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I have no sound.

Tried a lot of solutions like [that one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)

I tried almost every solutions in their forums and no result.

Comment: I also tried a lot of solutions in here and in askubuntu and nothing really worked. I do not have time for this because I need the environment for work. I will have to drop ubuntu and use fedora instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried many tutorials. but nothing worked out except this one

1. Check pipe wire-session-manager status

   sudo systemctl status pipewire-session-manager
2. If not running just Then start it

   sudo systemctl start pipewire-session-manager

I got this error while trying to start

```
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found while restart pipewire-session-manager
```

So restarted dbus

```
sudo systemctl restart dbus
```

This will log out your current session. Then restart the system.

Comment: I got Unit pipewire-session-manager.service could not be found.